# Проблема при скачивании изображений

Tags: python

Написал код для скачивания изображений.

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download
from script import query
# создаем объект класса google_images_download и задаем параметры поиска
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()
arguments = {"kali": query, "limit": 10, "format": "jpg", "output_directory": "C:/tmp"}
# запускаем загрузку изображений
response.download(arguments)
```

Он работает, но с одним НО.. изображения скачиваются в разрешении 162x90 162x108
Как скачать в разрешении хотя-бы 900х600

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте параметр size и указать желаемое разрешение в пикселях. Например: "size": "large"

Используйте параметр exact_size, чтобы указать точное разрешение изображения в пикселях. Например: "exact_size": "900,600"

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download
from script import query

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()
arguments = {
    "keywords": query,
    "limit": 10,
    "format": "jpg",
    "output_directory": "C:/tmp",
    "size": "large",  # добавили параметр размера
    "exact_size": "900,600"  # добавили параметр точного размера
}


response.download(arguments)
```

Обратите внимание, что эти параметры могут не работать для всех поисковых запросов, и некоторые изображения могут все еще иметь более низкое разрешение.

Comment: Не работает. выдает такие же изображения как и мой код. Вообще ничего не поменялось

Comment: Недостаточно изображений с заданным размером:
Если в базе данных Google Images недостаточно изображений с заданным размером, то библиотека гугла может загружать изображения более маленького размера, чтобы заполнить лимит изображений.

Некоторые изображения могут быть пропущены:
гугл может пропускать некоторые изображения, если они не соответствуют заданным параметрам. Это может произойти, если изображения слишком маленькие или если не смог распознать размер изображения.

попробуйте убрать `exact_size` оставить только `size`

Comment: а зачем мой запрос на "keywords" заменил?

Comment: Параметр "keywords"  отвечает за ключевые слова, по которым будут осуществляться поиск изображений.

Comment: можно еще добавить `"aspect_ratio": "wide"` чтобы указать, что надо скачивать изображения с широким соотношением сторон.

Comment: from google_images_download import google_images_download

    # задаем настройки скачивания изображений
    image_options = {
        "keywords": "kali linux",
        "output_directory": "C:/tmp",
        "format": "jpg",
        "limit": 30,
        "aspect_ratio": "wide"
    }

    # создаем экземпляр класса google_images_download
    google_downloader = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

    # запускаем скачивание изображений
    google_downloader.download(image_options)

    print("Картинки успешно скачаны!") теперь вообще ничего не скачивает